# Present Moment realization and Brahman realization same?

Tags: brahman

Many have realized present moment by reading the book
[The Power of Now by Eckhart Tolle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_of_Now)

It is a book which can give realization by the time you end reading the book. *Eckhart* teaches present moment is the only real thing.

I would like to know is the present moment realization same as brahman realization?

Comment: For those who realised Brahman, Mundaka Upanishad says 'Brahmavid Brhamaiva Bhavati' meaning he who realises Brahman becomes Brahman himself! For those who are aware of present moment we can not say any such thing! It may be more precisely termed as Dharana on present moment! Another thing is all bondage (Pashas) are cut off by Brahman realization, we can't say of such thing in case of present moment realization (though it might differ in the awareness level of the practitioner)....

Comment: No. Otherwise animals would have realized brahman.

Comment: No, even though Brahmgyanis are also mindful, but that mindfulness comes from Self-realization or Atman Gyan. Did Eckhart explain what Atman/Soul, the real Self is? If No, than bookish present moment realization is a commercial sham and can also be achieved with heavy drugs or heavy workouts or fasting.

Comment: Yes, he speaks about inner being, not mentioning it as atman or god

Comment: Well you have read the book and so did millions, but it didnot bring revolution in the world because Brahman realization is same as God-realization that was experienced by Jesus, Buddha, Krishna, etc., who revolutionized the world. So, in conclusion Guru is needed as Brahman/God/Self realization can't come from spiritual books but it can motivate to search further that something exists beyond what's seen, beyond death.

Comment: Your question is being voted closed as Eckhart Tolle is a new age writer, not a Hindu. I've read his Power of Now, and like many new age writers, he borrows what it likes from Hinduism to arrive at his own religious/philosophical story which are not Hindu. One should not rely on his writings to arrive at an understanding of either Hinduism or Buddhism or what these traditions view as realization.

Answer (score 2):

No, present moment cannot be the same as Brahman realization. One realizes Brahman after chittasuddhi (purity of heart). Chittasuddhi cannot be obtained by simply reading a book.

> MASTER (to the Brahmos): "Dive deep. Learn to love God. Plunge into
> divine love. You see, I have heard how you pray. Why do you Brahmos
> dwell so much on the glories of God? Is there such great need of your
> saying over and over again, 'O God, You have created the sky, the
> great oceans, the lunar world, the solar world, and the stellar
> world'?
>
> "Everybody is wonder-struck at the mere sight of a rich man's garden
> house. People become speechless at the sight of the trees, the
> flowers, the ponds, the drawing-room, the pictures. But alas, how few
> are they who seek the owner of all these! Only one or two inquire
> after him. He who seeks God with a longing heart can see Him, talk to
> Him as I am talking to you. Believe my words when I say that God can
> be seen. But ah! To whom am I saying these words? Who will believe me?
>
> "Can one find God in the sacred books? By reading the scriptures one
> may feel at the most that God exists. But God does not reveal Himself
> to a man unless he himself dives deep. Only after such a plunge, after
> the revelation of God through His grace, is one's doubt destroyed. You
> may read scriptures by the thousands and recite thousands of texts;
> but unless you plunge into God with yearning of heart, you will not
> comprehend Him. By mere scholarship you may fool man, but not God.
>
> "Scriptures and **books — what can one achieve with these alone?** Nothing
> can be realized without His grace. Strive with a longing heart for His
> grace. Through His grace you will see Him and He will talk to you."

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Chapter 32, Visit to the Sinthi Brahmo Samaj**

Comment: What a great answer sir !